# Why am I able to open executable files?

Tags: windows, files

I really don't know how to give many details here. All it is is that I can open exe files for some reason.

I'm not saying it's a bad thing, but I'm really confused. I am using Ubuntu 15.10. I can't install exe's that use online/server stuff, like Skype or LightShot, but I can install things like FL Studio and Notepad++, able to open them without opening any other emulation apps.

Comment: I believe you have Wine installed. That's the only explanation I can think of.

Comment: Open a terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T), type `wine`, and press Enter. What happens as a result?

Comment: yeah i got wine. i feel pretty stupid asking this lmao. But does Wine actually let you open exe's? I thought it only let you opened ones you added to a list.

Comment: Not all applications can be used with wine. Use linux applications instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You do have emulation apps.
Wine or mono for instance. Depending on what distribution you are using, one or more may come installed by default.

Comment: What does `mono` have to do with .exe files?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/

Comment: Wine Is Not an Emulator.

Answer (score -1):

press Ctrl, alt and t on your keyboard and paste this into the window that pops up

sudo apt-get install wine

then press enter

finally enter your password